# XSLT referencing to a variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling with a problem which comes up to this simple example. Why the output isn't dates of books, but just empty `<test/>` tag?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:b="http://www.demo.com/book">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Books">
        <xsl:for-each select="//b:books/b:book">
            <xsl:element name="qq"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="test">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Books"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the sample XML for books:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<b:books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.demo.com" xmlns:b="http://www.demo.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.demo.com book.xsd">
    <b:book id="1">
        <name>Hamlet</name>
        <date>2001-05-04</date>
        <authorId>1</authorId>
        <availability>false</availability>
    </b:book>
    <b:book id="2">
        <name>Macbeth</name>
        <date>2000-12-13</date>
        <authorId>1</authorId>
        <availability>false</availability>
    </b:book>
</b:books>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, the `date` element is also in that namespace so you need `<xsl:value-of select="b:date"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="date"/>`.

To output elementsv or nodes in general in a variable that is a result tree fragment you need `xsl:copy-of`, not `xsl:value-of` (which just creates a text node) so you want at least `<xsl:copy-of select="$Books"/>`.

Comment: and the namespaces in the XML are `http://www.demo.com`, but in the XSLT the prefix `b` is bound to `http://www.demo.com/book`. They need to match, or it won't find anything.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it

Comment: @MadsHansen, good catch, thanks, I thought I had checked for a namespace mismatch but horizontal scrolling need  inisde of code samples always kills my reading skills, it seems.